# Google Sheets - Add Offset and Where to a Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to add Offset 1 and a condition: where COUNT(A) > 0 to this query but wherever I try to add them I have an error

```
=QUERY(A:B,"SELECT A , COUNT(A) Group BY A LABEL COUNT(A) '' " ,
  1)
```

I tried but it doesn't work

```
=QUERY(A:B,"SELECT A , COUNT(A) Group BY A LABEL COUNT(A) Offset 1 WHERE COUNT(A)>0'' " ,
  1)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(A:B, "select A,count(A) group by A label count(A)''", 0)
```

or:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A:B, 
 "select A,count(A) group by A label count(A)''", 0), 
 "where Col2 > 0", 0)
```